# Make embedded PDF size relative : HTML

Tags: html, pdf, resize, embed

I currently have a PDF embedded in my website:

```
<body onload="startTime()">
    <div id="resume">
        <embed src="files/Resume.pdf" height="1250" width="975">
    </div>
    <h2 id="resumeNote">*Resume current as of 8/21/12</h2>
</body>
```

But I noticed that the sizing is not relative (it does not resize when the browser is resized). Most of the time it isn't an issue, but it looks a bit tacky when resizing. Is there any way to fix this? From what I've been able to find thus far it looks as if there is no option other than setting the PDF to display at a fixed height/width.

Comment: What does "embedded" mean exactly?

Comment: <body onload="startTime()">                       <div id="resume">  
<embed src="files/Resume.pdf" height="1250" width="975">  
</div>  
<h2 id="resumeNote">*Resume current as of 8/21/12</h2>  
</body>  
  
It's just a static HTML page.